# Github overwrites repository instead of adding to it

Tags: git, github

I have a repository named "projects" where I have one folder for one specific project. Now I am trying to upload a new folder to the same repo for a different project.

The local dir looks like this: Desktop/projects/project1/projectfiles

When I do a new project it is like: Desktop/projects/project2/project2files

1. First time I ran the following code from inside project1 so on GitHub repo it showed a folder called projectiles
2. 2nd time, I run the code from inside project2 so on Github instead of showing both folders, it now only shows the folder project2files

The Code:

```
git init
git remote add origin "url"
git add .
git commit -m "check" (edited: had a typo) 
git push origin master -f
```

it gives an error: 
*** ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to "url" ***
 if I don't use -f, couldn't resolve it

Comment: try running `git pull origin master` first, looks like your local files are behind the remote repository

Comment: @MateusJunges I tried that but doesn't seem to help. I added more information in the question. Could u please check it again thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing, but if you have a remote repository with existing commits, git init is not what you want to do. Before starting work you should clone the repository from the remote and then proceed to make your changes to what is already there.

Comment: create the git repo `Desktop/projects/` and **no other repository**. Or use `git submodule`.

Comment: @dan1st i eventually figured that's what I was doing wrong after being able to add it as a submodule. now I initialized the git in the projects/ and whenever anything changes inside the folder I start at git add . and it works perfectly! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense, fundamentally—you have two projects. You can push to two remotes (e.g., GitHub repos)—one per project—or have both projects’ files in one git repo. When you force pushed the second one (which was necessary, because the histories are not compatible), you overwrote the entire history from the first project.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be different repos for different projects, but this is for a class. so the class is the repo and inside it is projects I'll be doing. Yes, I can push them all at once at the end, but I want to add them as I do them. I

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot make a commit without a commit message. Running this command:

```
git commit -m""
```

Will simply abort the commit.  Try adding a proper message, like this:

```
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

You could also include the flag `--allow-empty-message` to allow the first commit, but in general empty messages are not allowed. For more information, take a look at the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

Comment: sorry that's a type the commit is going through it just overwrites what's already in the repo